# how get country name from r geocode

Tags: r, ggmap

I use `ggmap` library for getting country name from the list of addresses.

But it does not work as intended (at least [as described here](https://bcb.dfci.harvard.edu/%7Eaedin/courses/R/CDC/maps.html))

```r
r<-ggmap::geocode(c('harvard university', 'the vatican'), output = 'more')
glimpse(r)
```

result:

```r
Rows: 2
Columns: 9
$ lon     <dbl> -71.117, 12.453
$ lat     <dbl> 42.377, 41.903
$ type    <chr> "establishment", "country"
$ loctype <chr> "geometric_center", "approximate"
$ address <chr> "cambridge, ma, usa", "00120, vatican city"
$ north   <dbl> 42.378, 41.907
$ south   <dbl> 42.376, 41.900
$ east    <dbl> -71.115, 12.458
$ west    <dbl> -71.118, 12.446
```

How to get a country name in this case?

UPDATE:

If I provide an `output='all'` parameter, it returns a long nested list where in `address_components` there is a country name. What is the most efficient way to retrieve it?

CODE:

```r
r<-ggmap::geocode(c('harvard university', 'the vatican'), output = 'all')
glimpse(r)
```

RESULT:

```r
> str(r )
tibble [1 × 2] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 $ results:List of 1
  ..$ :List of 5
  .. ..$ address_components:List of 3
  .. .. ..$ :List of 3
  .. .. .. ..$ long_name : chr "New York"
  .. .. .. ..$ short_name: chr "New York"
  .. .. .. ..$ types     :List of 2
  .. .. .. .. ..$ : chr "locality"
  .. .. .. .. ..$ : chr "political"
  .. .. ..$ :List of 3
  .. .. .. ..$ long_name : chr "New York"
  .. .. .. ..$ short_name: chr "NY"
  .. .. .. ..$ types     :List of 2
  .. .. .. .. ..$ : chr "administrative_area_level_1"
  .. .. .. .. ..$ : chr "political"
  .. .. ..$ :List of 3
  .. .. .. ..$ long_name : chr "United States"
  .. .. .. ..$ short_name: chr "US"
  .. .. .. ..$ types     :List of 2
  .. .. .. .. ..$ : chr "country"
  .. .. .. .. ..$ : chr "political"
  .. ..$ formatted_address : chr "New York, NY, USA"
  .. ..$ geometry          :List of 4
  .. .. ..$ bounds       :List of 2
  .. .. .. ..$ northeast:List of 2
  .. .. .. .. ..$ lat: num 40.9
  .. .. .. .. ..$ lng: num -73.7
  .. .. .. ..$ southwest:List of 2
  .. .. .. .. ..$ lat: num 40.5
  .. .. .. .. ..$ lng: num -74.3
  .. .. ..$ location     :List of 2
  .. .. .. ..$ lat: num 40.7
  .. .. .. ..$ lng: num -74
  .. .. ..$ location_type: chr "APPROXIMATE"
  .. .. ..$ viewport     :List of 2
  .. .. .. ..$ northeast:List of 2
  .. .. .. .. ..$ lat: num 40.9
  .. .. .. .. ..$ lng: num -73.7
  .. .. .. ..$ southwest:List of 2
  .. .. .. .. ..$ lat: num 40.5
  .. .. .. .. ..$ lng: num -74.3
  .. ..$ place_id          : chr "ChIJOwg_06VPwokRYv534QaPC8g"
  .. ..$ types             :List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : chr "locality"
  .. .. ..$ : chr "political"
 $ status : chr "OK"
```

Comment: Do you get the country with `output = "all"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the `output = 'more'` argument is much easier to extract from. The last item is (probably) always the country.

```r
r<-ggmap::geocode(c('harvard university', 'the vatican'), output = 'more') %>% 
  mutate(
    country = stringr::str_extract(address, "(?<=, )[^,]*$") # everything after last comma
  )


# # A tibble: 2 x 10
#    lon   lat type          loctype          address             north south  east  west country     
#   <dbl> <dbl> <chr>         <chr>            <chr>               <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>       
# 1 -71.1  42.4 establishment geometric_center cambridge, ma, usa   42.4  42.4 -71.1 -71.1 usa         
# 2  12.5  41.9 country       approximate      00120, vatican city  41.9  41.9  12.5  12.4 vatican city
```

Alternatively, you can extract the 'country' from the deeply nested list with `purrr::pluck`, although you might have to do some work to find the appropriate index within 'address_components', because it looks like this changes.

```r
library(ggmap)
library(purrr)

r<-ggmap::geocode(c('harvard university', 'the vatican'), output = 'all')

# base r
r[[1]][[1]][[1]]$address_components[[3]]$long_name  # USA
r[[2]][[1]][[1]]$address_components[[1]]$long_name  # Vatican City

# purrr
purrr::pluck(r, 1, 1, 1, "address_components", 3, "long_name")
purrr::pluck(r, 2, 1, 1, "address_components", 1, "long_name")

# Result: 
# usa
# vatican city
```

EDIT: here's an more robust way to extract the country names.

```r
sapply(r, function(x) {
  # Simplify
  x_reduc <- x$results[[1]]$address_component

  # Loop for 'country' component
  for (i in seq_len(length(x_reduc[[1]]))) {
    component_type <- x_reduc[[i]]$types[[1]]
    if (component_type == 'country') return(x_reduc[[i]]$long_name)
  }
})
```

Comment: Yes, that should work (the first time in my life I realised that there is no single country in the world with a comma in its name :) )

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it's very bad way of doing it, but I figured out how to do it in a very ugly way (but it works):

```r
loc2country <- function(loc) {
  latlon <-
    ggmap::geocode(location = c(loc),
                   output = "latlon",
                   source = "google") %>% as_tibble()
  revgeo::revgeo(
    longitude = latlon$lon,
    latitude = latlon$lat,
    provider = 'google',
    API = api_key,
    output = 'hash',
    item = 'country'
  )$country
}

loc2country('Vienna')
```

returns:

```r
[1] "Austria"
```